# 3D Data Visualisation in Latex

Tags: tikz-datavisualization

Relative newbie to Latex visualisation, and I genuinely wouldn't know where to start with the type of visual I've given below.

However I am hoping someone could provide an example or signpost me towards a tutorial in which I could generate this type of 3D self-organising map (SOM) visualisation, whether in Latex or otherwise?

Overall, I am just looking to simulate a data cloud and place a flexible map/grid on top. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For reference, the graph was taken from this source:

http://bcbt.specs-lab.com/bcbt14/sites/default/files/event-files-public/Self-organizing%20maps%20Tutotial.pdf
[image]

Comment: I suggest two approaches: a) checking out these tags https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-3dplot , b) having a closer look into the minimal introduction and the sections about "Data visualization" in the big manual.

Comment: Check out the [pgfplots](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) package.

Comment: Thanks both. I appreciate your help.